# Writing array to console outputs type name

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to declare an array and send it to my DLL for sorting it by ascending order but I can't seem to make it work properly.

This is the output I get from the code below

[image]

Main Program

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values = {11, 5, 16, 9, 12, 39, 12};
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Class1.accendingArray(values));

            }
        }
    }   
}
```

DLL Code

```
namespace DLLProject
{
    public class Class1
    {
      public static int[] accendingArray(int[] values)
      {
        Array.Sort(values);
        return values;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DLL is returning a sorted array. However, in your main program, you are iterating through your array, wanting to print out each element. Try this instead:

```
values = Class1.accendingArray(values);
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(values[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, you could make your DLL return a `IEnumerable<int>` and then use `yield return` to iterate through it in the main program.

To do this, change your main program to this:

```
foreach (int i in accendingArray(values))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

And in your DLL, change it to this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> accendingArray(int[] values)
{
    Array.Sort(values);

    foreach (int i in values)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Knew it!  Thanks Icemanind!!

Comment: @Justin - Tim also pointed out that you are returning the same object you are modifying. Consider fixing this so it's not redundant.

Comment: do you mean simply changing the name from values to something else?

Comment: @Justin - No. I mean, make it so that accendingArray returns `void`. `Array.Sort()` sorts the array. There is no reason to return the array. In your main program, you can just simply call `accendingArray(values);`. No need to reassign values to same array your function is returning.

Comment: I apologize but could you actually give me the code example?  I'm trying to do what you're suggesting but I keep getting stranger errors.  I must be making a mistake somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems-- you are sorting the entire array every time through the loop, and then you are trying to print the .ToString() representation of that result of the entire array each time through the loop. Try this instead:

```
int[] values = {11, 5, 16, 9, 12, 39, 12};
int[] sortedValues = Class1.accendingArray(values);
for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sortedValues[i]);
}
```

Also, in your DLL, you are returning the same object you are modifying.  This is redundant.  It works, but is probably not what you are intending.

Comment: thanks for your help.  Could you clarify a little more about what you mean regarding returning the same object I'm modifying in my DLL?

Comment: `Array.Sort(values)` is sorting the `values` array in-place, which is actually the same array you passed in, not a copy of it.  You are returning the same reference back that was passed in, and then assigning it back to the same variable that you passed in.  The calling `values` array was already sorted at that point, no need to return or it or reassign it

Comment: I apologize, but could you show me the code for this?  I'm still not following

Comment: Not sure how to illustrate this in code, but if you simply call `Class1.accendingArray(values);` and ignore the return value, it will still work.  `values = Class1.accendingArray(values);` is the same thing as stating `Class1.accendingArray(values);  values = values;` since `Class1.accendingArray()` returns whatever array reference you pass in to it.

Comment: Okay I think I'm following you now.  So if I simply remove the additional 'value' in front of Class1.accendingArray(values); it will take care of the problem?  I don't need to change my DLL library code correct?

Comment: So if your goal is to create a method that returns a sorted *copy* of the source input without modifying that original, then no, keep the assignment and modify the DLL to copy the array, sort it, and return the copy.  If your goal is to create a method that modifes the existing array you pass to it to be sorted, then yes, remove the reassignment; and further it would make sense to also make the DLL library have a void return type and omit the return statement.  It then becomes a 1-line method `void accendingArray(int[] values) { Array.Sort(values); }`.